# Having trouble writing tokenizer

Tags: c++, io, tokenize

I am writing a tokenizer in c++.  What it is going to do is search a file for strings characters enclosed in "", and the symbols [ and ].  The it is going to create a token object of it, and store it in  a vector. It is supposed to ignore all whitespace characters by calling input.get()  to skip over them, but i am not sure this is the correct way to do this.  I also feel like i could have made stupid error such as == instead of =.  Here is my current code

```
vector<Token> tokenize(wstring file)
{
    ifstream input = ifstream(file);
    vector<Token> tokens;

    while(input.peek() != std::char_traits<char>::eof())
    {
        wchar_t ch = (wchar_t) input.peek();

        if (isspace(ch)) 
        {
            input.get();
        }
        else if(ch == '[' || ch == ']')
        {
            input.get();
            wstring str(&ch);
            tokens.push_back(Token(SYMBOL, str));
        }
        else if (ch == '"') 
        { 
            wstringstream accum; 
            input.get();

            while(input.peek() != '"')
            {
                if(input.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::eof())
                    endProgram(L"Unterminated String Literal");

                accum<<input.peek();
                input.get();
            }

            tokens.push_back(Token(STRING, accum.str()));
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
    {
        wcout<<tokens.at(i).getData()<<endl;
    }

    return tokens;
}
```

However when i run this code on a file like this

```
] ]
"ddsd"

"sdsd"

[[]]]]][[
```

I get my error UnterminatedStringLiteral what am i doing wrong?  I am new to c++ by the way so a simple explantion would be nice.

Comment: Note that the failure result of `in.peek()` spells `std::char_traits<char>::eof()` and not `-1`. Although `-1` a value typically used, it isn't required that the value is `-1`.

Comment: `else if (ch = '"')` Can you see it? ;)

Comment: fixed that but still get error

Answer (score 0):

Your code may get more complicated when adding more "tokens".
I suggest either using a `switch` statement:

```
switch (ch)
{
    case '[':
        //...
        break;
    case ']':
        //...
        break;
// ...
    default:
        //...
        break;
};
```

Or using a lookup table with function pointers:

```
  typedef (void)(*Function_Pointer_Type)(char ch);
  struct Lookup_Table_Entry
  {
     char   token;
     Function_Pointer_Type token_processor_func;
  };

  static const Lookup_Table_Entry  token_table[] =
  {
    { '[', Open_Bracket_Handler},
    { ']', Close_Bracket_Handler},
    { '\"', String_Delimiter},
  };
  static const unsigned int    token_table_size =
    sizeof(token_table) / sizeof(token_table[0]);

  //...
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < token_table_size; ++i)
  {
     if (ch == token_table[i].token)
     {
        token_table[i].token_processor_func(ch);
        break;
     }
  }
```

Both of these code fragments are cleaner and can handle the case where a character is not a token.

The table lookup allows easier expansion of the code, should more tokens be added.

Answer (score 0):

I made code like these..

```
  ///    if(*parm_data == ' ' || *parm_data == ';' || *parm_data == '|' 
     //   || *parm_data == '\t' || *parm_data == ',') break; 

        char *CHXLog::GetToken(char *parm_data, char *parm_token)
        {
            while(*parm_data != 0 && *parm_data != '\n')
            { 

                if( *parm_data == ',' )
                {       
                    break; 
                }
                else 
                {
                    *parm_token =*parm_data; 
                }
                parm_data++; 
                parm_token++; 
            } 

            *parm_token = '\0'; 

            return parm_data + 1; 

        }
```

Comment: I am not sure i understand what you are doing, i don't see how that relates to my original code

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem, in this code,

```
        while(input.peek() != '"')
        {
            if(input.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::eof())
                endProgram(L"Unterminated String Literal");

            accum<<input.peek();
            input.get();
        }

        tokens.push_back(Token(STRING, accum.str()));
```

there should have been an

```
input.get();
```

to skip the " character